# Java - Printing format with super class

Tags: java, bluej

The printout of my MediaCollection is not in format that I want it to be. When I print MediaCollection details from a file it does show this:

[image: MediaCollection printout]

Where I rather want it to show something like that:

[image: DVD only printout]

---

### This is my super class

```
public class MediaFormat
{
    public String title;
    public int releaseDate;
    public double price;

    public MediaFormat(String title, int releaseDate, double price)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * Change the title.
     */

    public void changeTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     * Change Release Date.
     */

    public void changeReleaseDate (int releaseDate)
    {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    /**
     * Return Price of a CD or DVD.
     */

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ("\n" + "Title - " + title + "\n" + "Release Date - " + releaseDate + "\n" +    "Price - " + price + "\n"); 
    }
 }
```

---

### This is my CD Class

```
public class CD extends MediaFormat
{
    // Defining variables
    public String artist;
    public int playingTime;
    public int nuOfTracks;

    /**
     * Create new constructor for CD object, with all appropriate details.
     */

    public CD(int releaseDate, String title, String artist, int playingTime, int nuOfTracks, double price)
    {
        super(title, releaseDate, price);
        this.artist = artist;
        this.playingTime = playingTime;
        this.nuOfTracks = nuOfTracks;
    }

    /**
     * Change the Artista Name.
     */

    public void changeArtist(String Artist)
    {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    /**
     * Change Playing Time Duration.
     */

    public void changePlayingTime(int playingTime)
    {
        this.playingTime = playingTime;
    }

    /**
     * Change the number of tracks.
     */

    public void changenuOfTracks(int nuOfTracks)
    {
        this.nuOfTracks = nuOfTracks;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String additionals = super.toString();
        return additionals + ("\n" + "Artist - " + artist + "\n" + "Playing Time - " + playingTime + "min" + "\n" + "nuOfTracks - " + nuOfTracks + "\n"); 
    }
}
```

---

### This is my DVD class

```
public class DVD extends MediaFormat
{
    public String director;
    public String rating;
    public int duration;

    /**
     * Create new constructor for DVD object, with all appropriate details.
     */

    public DVD(int releaseDate, String rating, String director, String title, int duration, double price)
    {
        super(title, releaseDate, price);
        this.rating = rating;
        this.director = director;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    /**
     * Change the director.
     */

    public void changeDirector(String director)
    {
        this.director = director;
    }

    /**
     * Change rating details.
     */

    public void changeRating(String rating)
    {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    /**
     * Change duration.
     */

    public void changeDuration(int duration)
    {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String additionals = super.toString();
        return additionals =
        ("\n" + "Rating - " + rating + "\n" + "Director - " + director + "\n" + "Duration - " + duration + "\n"); 
    }
 }
```

---

### This is my Media Collection class

```
public class MediaCollection 
{    
    //declaration of Media collection
    //this is an array + total price

    private ArrayList<MediaFormat> collection = new ArrayList<MediaFormat>();
    private double totalPrice;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MediaCollection
     */
    public MediaCollection()
    {        
    }

    /**
     * reads in DVD information to the collection from a file 
     * @param  inputFileName  the name of the file containing 
     * the DVD information
     */ 
    public void readInMedia(String inputFileName)
    {
        FileReader reader;
        try
        {
            reader = new FileReader(inputFileName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
            while (in.hasNextLine())
            {
                String mediaInfo = in.nextLine();
                Scanner fields = new Scanner(mediaInfo).useDelimiter("\\s*;\\s*");

                String mediaType = fields.next().trim();

                if(mediaType.equals("DVD")){
                    int releaseDate = fields.nextInt();
                    String rating = fields.next().trim();
                    String director = fields.next().trim();
                    String title = fields.next().trim();
                    int duration = fields.nextInt();
                    double price = fields.nextDouble();

                    //create a DVD object and add it to your collection.
                    DVD d = new DVD(releaseDate, rating, director, title, duration, price);
                    collection.add(d);
                    totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
                }

                if(mediaType.equals("CD")){
                    int releaseDate = fields.nextInt();
                    String title = fields.next().trim();
                    String artist = fields.next().trim();
                    int playingTime = fields.nextInt();
                    int nuOfTracks = fields.nextInt();
                    double price = fields.nextDouble();

                    //create a CD object and add it to the collection.
                    CD c = new CD(releaseDate, title, artist, playingTime, nuOfTracks, price);
                    collection.add(c);
                    totalPrice = totalPrice + price;
                }

            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Error processing file" 
                + exception);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("incorrect file format" 
                + exception);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Input was not a number" 
                + exception);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the for loop which prints details for each instance in the collection.
     */
    public void printMediaList()
    {
        for (int i=0; i< (collection.size()); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(collection.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    public void printTotal()
    {
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Total Price in pounds - ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", totalPrice);
    }
 }
```

Comment: "When I print MediaCollection details from a file" -- Can you share the file format as well  ?

Comment: the file format is txt (Text Document)

Comment: I am sorry. I meant the contents of the file

Comment: DVD; 1994; 15; Frank Darabont; The Shawshank Redemption; 142; 3
DVD; 1972; 18; Francis Ford Coppola; The Godfather; 175; 9.52
CD; 2014; Popular Problems; Leonard Cohen; 33; 9; 7.98
DVD; 1994; 18; Quentin Tarantino; Pulp Fiction; 154; 4.97
CD; 1972; St Dominic's Preview; Van Morrison; 40; 7; 14.75... and so on.

Comment: Your `DVD#toString()` is strange, you probably want a `+` not a `=` in `return additionals = ("\n" + "Rating - " + rat...`

Comment: yeah that's one of the mistakes which I just saw and corrected but it still does not solve my issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small problem with your DVD.java and CD.java. Here are the changes.

CD.java

```
 public String toString()
    {
        return  ("Title - "+title + "\nArtist - " + artist + "\nRelease Date"+ releaseDate+"\nNumber Of Tracks - " +nuOfTracks+"\nDuration - " + playingTime + "min" + "\nPrice - $"+price+"\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
```

DVD.java

```
 public String toString()
    {
        return  ("Title - "+title + "\nDirector - " + director + "\nRelease Date - "+ releaseDate+"\nRating - " +rating+"\nDuration - " + duration + "min" + "\n"+"Price - $"+price)+"\n---------------------------------------------------------------------";
    }
```

You need not call super in toString. As DVD and CD extends MediaFormat class the properties of MediaFormat are visible in the child classes (DVD and CD). And little format to your output gets your desired result

**Output:**   Please note that i dont have a pound symbol on my keyboard, so replaced it with a $   ;) please change it accordingly in your CD and DVD java files

```
Title - The Shawshank Redemption
Director - Frank Darabont
Release Date - 1994
Rating - 15
Duration - 142min
Price - $3.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Title - The Godfather
Director - Francis Ford Coppola
Release Date - 1972
Rating - 18
Duration - 175min
Price - $9.52
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Title - Popular Problems
Artist - Leonard CohenRelease Date2014
Number Of Tracks - 9
Duration - 33min
Price - $7.98
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Title - Pulp Fiction
Director - Quentin Tarantino
Release Date - 1994
Rating - 18
Duration - 154min
Price - $4.97
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Title - St Dominic's Preview
Artist - Van MorrisonRelease Date1972
Number Of Tracks - 7
Duration - 40min
Price - $14.75
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: okay this works by I though I need to somehow reference to the super class with the variables which are not in it. Thank you.